# Laravel namespacing routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have controllers in different folder than Laravel native `App\Http\Controllers`. I am using a custom `Lib\MyApp` folder which has modules inside. Each module has its own controllers, models etc. I added to `composer.json` autoloading to `app\lib`.

What I did is change `RouteServiceProvider` namespace:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Lib\MyApp';
```

I did a `composer dump-autoload` after everything.

Inside `MyApp` is a `Landing\Controller` folder with actual controller class inside.

**Try 1 (ideal):**

I would like to call my route like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'Landing\Controller\LandingController@index');
```

But this way I am getting a `ReflectionException` that the class is not found even though

**Try 2:**

```
Route::get('/', '\Landing\Controller\LandingController@index');
```

Trailing slash gets rid of the namespace part when I refresh the page, and class is still said not to exist.

**Try 3:**

```
Route::get('/', 'MyApp\Landing\Controller\LandingController@index');
```

This just duplicates `MyApp` folder, and class is not found as expected.

**Try 4 (working, but don't want it like that)**

```
Route::get('/', '\MyApp\Landing\Controller\LandingController@index');
```

This works fine, although I would like to get rid of the `\MyApp\` part.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: What about namespace like this : `Route::namespace('Landing\Controller')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'LandingController@index');
    // + other routes in the same namespace
});` ??

Comment: Although I like the approach, this one doesn't work with any combination

Comment: I think it must work according to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-namespaces) :p

Comment: Yeah, but I have no idea what am I doing wrong...probably some wrong slash or something. The funny thing is that it is giving me back an error that class doesn't exist, even though the path it throws out is correct...

Comment: Waht did you add to the composer file ?? and is Lib insidethe App folder ?

Comment: I wrote up there what is in composer. Yeah, lib is inside app. I thought maybe capitalization problem because lib is actually lowercase...but no avail

Comment: One more thing did you namecpaced the `LandingController` like this `<?php namespace App\Lib\MyApp\Landing\Controller;` ??

Comment: BOOM! Right on the spot :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the namespace in the routes for that purpose :

```
Route::namespace('Landing\Controller')->group(function () { 
    Route::get('/', 'LandingController@index'); 
    // + other routes in the same namespace 
});
```

And dont forget to add the namespace to the controllers :

```
<?php namespace App\Lib\MyApp\Landing\Controller;
```

PS : in the case where the Lib is inside the App folder there is no need to add a thing in the composer file, because the App folder is registred in the `psr-4` and with this it will load all the files within this namespase for you.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to add the namespace in Laravel

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'prefix','namespace'=>'Admin'], function () {
    // your routes with"App\Http\Controllers\Admin" Namespace
});

Route::namespace('Admin')->group(function () {
    // your routes with"App\Http\Controllers\Admin" Namespace
});

//single route
Route::namespace('Admin')->get('/todo', 'TaskController@index');

//single route
Route::get('/todo', 'Admin/TaskController@index');


// by ->namespace
Route::prefix('admin')->namespace('Admin')->group(function () {
    // route code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For "laravel 8"
Here I have given an example with both namespace and prefix but you can also use any one according to your requirement.

I created Controller in Controllers dir with command

> php artisan make:controller Admin/StoriesController

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/deleted_stories', 
    '\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\StoriesController@index')->name
    ('admin.stories.index');
});
```